# Why is the Taylor Series of tan⁻¹x valid for x=1?

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, integral-inequality, trigonometric-series, trigonometric-integrals

For -1 < x < 1,
$$\dfrac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x²+x³+...$$
Then $$\frac{1}{1-(-x²)}= 1-x²+x⁴-x⁶+...$$

Integrating both sides with respect to x from 0 to x we obtain,
tan⁻¹x = $$x - \dfrac{x³}{³} + \dfrac{x^⁵}{⁵}+...$$

Now my question is why this series of tan⁻¹x is valid for 1 although our initial series was only valid for -1 < x < 1  ?

Comment: Use [Taylor's theorem with integral rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) on $\arctan x$ and prove the rest tends to $0$.

Comment: Or use alternating series test?

Comment: @KennyLau Ah, yes, then Abel's theorem!

Comment: Or just use definition?

Comment: @KennyLau The definition proves the series is convergent, not that it tends to $\arctan 1$ (the radius if $1$, and everything can happen on the boundary of the convergence disk, except that Abel's theorem allows to conclude here). The OP asks why the series is valid for $1$, so I interpret he wants to prove both.

Comment: The OP is just a high school student. It would be appreciated if you state the main reason without directing me to such theorems!

Answer (score 1):

The series is convergent at $x=1$. Abel's theorem states that if
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$
is convergent, then the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
is continuous on the set $(-1,1]$. Here, $f(x)=\tan^{-1}x$
and so $$1-\frac13+\frac15-\cdots=\lim_{x\to1^-}\tan^{-1}x=\frac\pi4.$$